# sound_play action client c++

Tags: ros, c++, action-client, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
Anyone knows how to use the sound_play action_lib client request c++ version?
I've see that only a python test file is available.
Thank you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266590/sound_play-action-client-c++/) by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2017-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2017-08-02**:
some of the examples in C++ are given [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/master/sound_play/test/test.cpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it alone because there's nothing about it on the wiki or other pages (only python)
For who will be in my same situation, I post some code snippet
Here is what is needed to be included

```
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
#include <sound_play/SoundRequestAction.h>
```

The definition of the Action Client

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<sound_play::SoundRequestAction> SoundClientTest;
```

The definition of the Sound Client Goal

```
sound_play::SoundRequestGoal goal;
```

All the other things are the same as, for ex, the move base action client.
I hope this could be helpful

---

Originally posted by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) with karma: 185 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1